# LoadWith works incorrenctly for one-to-many association

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

For example, I have associated tables `XOrder` and `XUser`. I added them to DBML file in editor and created one-to-many association there. Now I have property `User` in `XOrder` and `Orders` in `XUser`. I want to load all user's orders in single SQL query with user. I tried `DataLoadOptions.LoadWith` method and discovered I can't do this. When I do `dataContext.GetTable<XUser>().ToArray()` Linq-To-SQL generates one SQL query to get all users from database and then zillion SQL queries to get all associated orders for every user - this is not what I want. Is there any way to tell Linq-to-SQL to use `JOIN` instead?

How Entity Framework addresses this issue?

**UPDATE.** So... What is the reason to use `LoadWith` instead of default lazy loading? Both create N+1 SQL queries.

Comment: Yes, cann `.Join` instead of `.ToArray` => http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C

Comment: I understand that I can `Join` or, better, `GroupJoin`, but I want to load everything transparently using Linq-to-SQL, is it possible?

Comment: @Denis, FWIW, in my experience EF will execute one query but return one row per child row, with all the data from the parent duplicated for each child.  This may or may not be ideal depending on the situation.